# How to take more than one rows from condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables. First contains the following columns: `id`, `names` and `id_of_exec`, the other: `id_of_exec` and `name_of_exec`. I want to join them, but I'm having a problem with the join condition:

```
ON (x.id_of_exec = y.id_of_exec AND ( y.name = "XYZ" OR y.name = "ABC"))
```

(Names - XYZ and ABC have different `id_of_exec`)
And there is problem because column `id_of_exec` has the same `id_of_exec` for more than one id and SQL shows me only `y.name = "XYZ"`. How to get results of both `XYZ + ABC`. On the end I'm grouping by names because I need to get just names from 1st table where there are names from 2nd table `XYZ + ABC`.
I tried to use select behind AND but select returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Pls see the following guidance on asking a good sql related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table definitions, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: I don't find your question easy to understand because of the way it's written- it's kinda like in the movies when someone phones the superhero up babbling uncontrollably down the phone and he's like "whoa, slow down! What's going on?"  Please post up: some example data from your tables, the actual query you have written, the results you're getting, example results that you actually want

Comment: Don't GROUP BY !

Comment: This may be because 1. different data types or 2. information containing in one column of a id_of_exec be present in the main table of id_of_exec

Answer (score 0):

```
ON (x.id_of_exec = y.id_of_exec )
where ( y.name = "XYZ" OR y.name = "ABC")
```

The above query will join only on id_of_exec and then filter the records based on the values `"XYZ"` or `"ABC"`      .

Comment: Hope this is what you are looking for